# Which is correct definition between $J^i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^i_{~jk}J^{jk}$ and $J^i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}J^{jk}$?

Tags: angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, lie-algebra

The generators of the Lorentz group are denoted by $J^{\mu\nu}$ (suppose they are defined in terms of raised indices, as shown). From this, in my opinion, the angular momentum generators $J^i$'s and $J_i$'s should be defined as $$J_i\equiv\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}J^{jk}$$ and $$J^i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^i_{~jk}J^{jk}$$ where $\epsilon^i_{~ml}=\epsilon^{ijk}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$. This kind of positioning of indices $j,k$ is required since they must be contracted. But instead, I see the definition is given as $$J^i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}J^{jk}$$ or $$J_i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}J_{jk}$$ Since contraction of an index happens when it appears once upstairs and once downstairs how are the last two equations meaningful? Which are correct and which are wrong? And why? I also want to understand if there is a difference between $J^i$ and $J_i$. Please help!

Comment: What are your $J^i$s supposed to be (in order to decide which definition is "correct" we need to know what you're trying to define!)? What is a $\epsilon$ with mixed indices supposed to mean here (i.e. what are you using to raise/lower the indices)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind please check the edited post

Comment: Start off from the full 4 D covariant definitions and you should see the results easily. It is better to learn than be spoon fed.

Comment: Depending on the author it could either be sloppy notation or, since they only used latin indices, could be a result of the Minkowski metric. If the metric is defined with positive space components: $\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag[-1,1,1,1]$ then the upper and lower indices are equal (as long as you only consider the space components)

Comment: @all I have posted an answer. Please let me know what you think about its correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that to start with, the generators of the Lorentz group are defined in terms of raised indices and denoted by $J^{\mu\nu}$. Next, it is possible to define $J_{\mu\nu}$ i.e. generators with lowered indices as $$J_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\nu\rho}J^{\sigma\rho}.$$ As a passing remark, we note that since $J^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric, $J_{\mu\nu}$ is also antisymmetric. This immediately leads to the relations $$J_{0i}=-J_{i0}=-J^{0i}=J^{i0}, ~~J_{jk}=-J_{kj}=J^{jk}=-J^{kj}$$ where I used $\eta={\rm diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. Now we can define $J^i$ and $J_i$ as follows: $$J^i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}J_{jk}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk}J^{jk}~~~~~~~~ {\rm and} ~~~~~~J_i\equiv \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}J^{jk}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}J_{jk}.$$ Since there is no distinction between $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and $\epsilon^{ijk}$, we conclude that $J_i=J^i$.